# In need of regex assistance

Tags: regex

Since I rarely write my own regular expressions, this is one of few times I'm not sure where to begin. I am faced with a problem dealing with an unknown number of integers delimited with dashes. Since it's hard to visualize, I'll give an example...

```
LHZ345-347-348-349-362-363-LMZ323-342-344-345-346-180100-
```

Given this statement, a regex should return:

```
LHZ345-347-348-349-362-363-
LMZ323-342-344-345-346-180100-
```

With this is mind, I need to write a regex that checks for a 3 A-Z characters followed immediately by a 3 digit integer. From then on, any number of 3 digit integer + dash pairs may follow except for the last digit pair which may be of any length. Only dashes, integers 0-9, and capital characters A-Z are used.

If there are any regex geniuses out there willing to help me out if this is a simply enough problem, that would be awesome. If not, It would be great if you could direct me to a site that you feel would be helpful. Thanks in advance for any assistance! - Brandon

**Edit 1:** As to show some attempts, `[A-Z]{3}...\d+-` is all I have. To my knowledge this should work, but I'm stuck at the unknown number of integers in the middle part.

**Edit 2:** What changes to the regexes posted in the answers below are needed to accept dashes OR > signs in between the 3 digit integers? Also, I can't seem to input the regex into preg_match() and have all test cases work yet the same regex works in online testers such as regexpal.

Comment: Show us your attempts.

Comment: The site as requested: [the best regular expressions tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: Try them yourself with trial and error, here are some links: [ONE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) and [TWO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Edited per request...I didn't think it was anything of substance but I guess I'll include anything I have in the future. Sorry about the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

[Working for your sample data:](http://regexr.com?37mgg)

```
[A-Z]{3}([0-9]{3}\-)+[0-9]+\-
```

Comment: No need to escape hyphens here

Comment: @Eric depends on the regexp engine I think, vaguely remember seeing some errors about it in the past. Anyway doesn't really matter if you 'overly escape' in regexp, it's silently ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your regex:

```
[A-Z]{3}(?:\d{3}-)+\d+-
```

Decomposed:

- `[A-Z]{3}` -- 3 A-Z characters
- `(?: ... )+` -- one or more

  - `\d{3}-` -- 3-digit integer + dash pairs
- `\d+-` -- last digit pair which may be of any length

Comment: Works perfect with online regex testers but not in my php script...preg_match('/[A-Z]{3}(?:\d{3}-)+\d+-/', $string, $array); What's wrong? It has to be something extremely minor that I'm not catching.

Comment: Also, what change would be necessary to check not only for a dash, but either a - sign or a > sign?