# How to make a minor regex modification?

Tags: php, regex

Regarding this question: [In need of regex assistance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646736) and specifically this regex: "[A-Z]{3}(?:\d{3}-)+\d+-", what is the best way to accommodate instead of only dashes, > signs in between integer groups?

```
LHZ345-347>348-349>362>363-LMZ323-342-344-345-346-180100-
```

should result in

```
LHZ345-347>348-349>362>363-
LMZ323-342-344-345-346-180100-
```

In addition, how should this regex be implemented in PHP. My line of code:

```
preg_match("/[A-Z]{3}(?:\d{3}-)+\d+-/", $string, $array);
```

only finds the first instance of the string when online validators find them all on the same exact input string. Thanks - Brandon

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("/[A-Z]{3}(?:\d{3}[-\>])+\d+-/", $string, $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to find all matches of a certain regex you have to use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all). Matching multiple characters at the same place is done with a character class: `[->]`

```
php > preg_match_all("/[A-Z]{3}(?:\d{3}[->])+\d+-/", "LHZ345-347>348-349>362>363-LMZ323-342-344-345-346-180100-", $matches);
php > var_dump($matches);
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "LHZ345-347>348-349>362>363-"
    [1]=>
    string(30) "LMZ323-342-344-345-346-180100-"
  }
}
```